# How can i pause my code in android and have it wait for a button to be Pressed?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have multiple buttons and when their pressed they display information to the user(asking for a input) then i want the program to wait till the enter button is pressed to get the input so it can be used in the code. whats the best way for me to do this?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button enter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);
    Button line = (Button) findViewById(R.id.line);
    Button arc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.arc);

    line.setOnClickListener(this);
    enter.setOnClickListener(this);
    arc.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView vector = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.point);
    TextView index = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.index);
    TextView info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
    EditText cl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    DrawingUtils call = new DrawingUtils();
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.line:
        info.setText("Input X,Y,Z");
        // This Is Where the Wait Function Will GO till enter is pressed
        vector.setText(call.addVertice());
        index.setText("1");

        break;
    case R.id.enter:
        String In = cl.getText().toString();
        call.setInputCoords(In);
        break;
    case R.id.arc:
        info.setText("Enter Vertice1 ");
        // Code for entering Vertice1(Also has wait function)
        info.setText("Enter Vertice2");
        // Code for entering Vertice2(Also has wait function)
        info.setText("Enter Height");
        //Code for entering Height(Also has wait function)

    }

}
```

}

Comment: GUI code really should not wait, however there's helper code to make this easier. http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-alert-dialog-example/

Comment: I think it will be better if you illustrate what you mean with pictures, because I see that you're hardcoding a certain text on the text view and I don't see where it can be inserted manually.

Comment: @duty thanks that help me out. With that I can Increase my opengl view on my screen without having the edittext and the enter button on there . If you post as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Question is really hazy! Am assuming there are say 3 buttons on the UI which does some kind of calculation prompting the user for inputs and then all these calculations are used when the enter button is hit.

1>Keep a separate "submit" button on your screen.so when all of the calculations are done by the user he can "submit" it. 
2>If the calculations are long running ones(More than 5 seconds) put it inside a separate thread so that it doesn't freeze the UI and give an ANR.

Hope this helps.If not please make the question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should edit the question to clarify what your asking exactly.

Like you've been told, the main thread (also known as the GUI thread) shouldn't wait. Anyway, If I understand your case correctly, this isn't really required here. You can just change the implementation so instead of 'waiting', the action you want to apply is called after the input is received from the user and validated.

Your activity can have a boolean flag for each input your app requires for this the action  you run when the button is pressed.

```
boolean firstInput, secondInput, thirdInput;
```

For each input, you'll have a validation method:

```
private validateInput(View v)
{
    if (v.getText() != null){ //...and any other required rule to match for your action to function properly
        firstInput = true; //depends on the input you are checking.
    }
}
```

You can call validateInput() when the value in your input [changes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134144/android-edittext-onchange-listener)

Than, on the button's onClick:

```
if (firstInput && secondInput && thirdInput && everythingElseIsOk){
    //Energize!
    ...
} else {
    //One of the inputs isn't happy. Prompt the user to fix this, 
    //throw an exception or do nothing.
    return;
}
```

Also, I see no reason to put:

```
TextView vector = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.point);
TextView index = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.index);
TextView info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
EditText cl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Inside the onClick handler. It is more appropriate to init this just once, for example on `onCreate()`