# How to avoid a StackOverflow when formatting an Android EditText in realtime?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, stack-overflow

In my Android app I've got an EditText in which the user can enter an amount. When the EditText loses focus I format the entered amount to a currency Locale using NumberFormat, and when the user clicks the edittext, it takes the original string again and enters that ([code here](http://pastebin.com/VG8V5eaV)).

This works fine, but it doesn't really look pretty while the user enters the amount. Ideally I would like the EditText to also display the following (in order of importance):

1. the Currency symbol on the left of the amount.
2. Localised thousand separators.
3. Decimal mark only if it is entered by the user.

The first problem I run into however, is that when I use a TextWatcher and implement something like the snippet below, I get a (how well suited to this website) StackOverflowException, because it then watches its own change.

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    amount_field.setText("€" + s.toString());
}
```

So my question: how do you format an EditText in realtime? All tips are welcome!

Comment: try this for the textwatcher http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134144/android-edittext-onchange-listener

Comment: You can always remove the textwatcher, set the text and add the textwatcher. Not really a clean solution but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using on OnFocusChangeListener in following way:

```
<EDIT-TEXT>.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
        if(!arg1){//it means focus is shifted
            amount_field.setText("€" + s.toString());
        }

    }
});
```

Try doing something like this:

```
String lastText="";
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if(!lastText.equals(s.toString())){
       String str=s.toString();
       str = str.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
       Locale dutch = new Locale("nl", "NL");
       NumberFormat numberFormatDutch = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(dutch);
       String formattedAmount = numberFormatDutch.format(new BigDecimal(str));
       formattedAmount ="€" + formattedAmount;
       lastText=formattedAmount;
       amount_test.setText(formattedAmount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but doesn't `if(!arg1) {` mean that the EditText just lost focus? That is not the problem unfortunately. I currently already format the field while after it lost focus (see my current code: http://pastebin.com/VG8V5eaV) I want the EditText to change *during* the editing by the user.