# Best way to get int from user

Tags: android

I'm needing to get an integer from the user for one of my apps and I have tried using a text edit but it didn't seem to work, so I'm wanting to know another way of getting an integer from the user. The int will be positive numbers only and no more than 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use EditText.. then from in Your Activity

```
String s = ed.getText().ToString();
int i = 0;
if(s!=null)
i= Integer.valueOf(s);
```

To make sure keyboard only show numbers, 
make sure you add

```
android:input="number"
```

to your EditText in the XML

**UPDATE**

```
      yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

         String s = yourEditText.getText().ToString();
         int i = 0;
         if(s!=null)
          i= Integer.valueOf(s);
      }

      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
   });
```

Comment: This is what I was using and it wouldn't work. Where would I put this code since it needs to run every time the edittext is edited.

Comment: You have to create a button and set and OnClickListener on it so when the user finish he can click on the button.

Inside the onClickListener you can out the above code

Comment: or you can have an OnChangeLisener and still put the above code inside it

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11134227/2040750

Comment: So I might as well use an alert dialog

Comment: If you mean an AlertDialog with EditText yes definitely you can

Answer (score 0):

Use [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)

You can limit the number of digits [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285412/limit-text-length-of-edittext-in-android)

**Update:** 
Then you need to add a listener

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)

a relevant question:

[android edittext onchange listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134144/android-edittext-onchange-listener)

Comment: yes that's what I was doing but I would prefer a different way so that it updates the int when the user edits the text

Answer (score 0):

you can use properties in your XML .

use this line to limit input text in numbers in XML :

```
android:inputType="number"
```

and use this line to set your specific character:

```
android:digits="1234567890"
```

i think it is the best way for this purpose.