# How to replace entered text with new text - Custom keyboard android?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

Suppose i am having shortcuts codes for templates like following,

##waf  - Where are you from ?
   ##hoay - How old are you ?
   ##ibrn - I am busy right now.

I need to create a custom keyboard. In which, if i entered the short codes, it must be replace with the template . Is android Input methods api supporting this ?.

Comment: @PankajKumar constans? what constants?

Comment: @PankajKumar he is working on a custom keyboard,  not any text change listener

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the link . 
[android edittext onchange listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134144/android-edittext-onchange-listener)

at this area

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
   switch(textboxvalue)
   {
    case xxxx:
    setanytext ;
    break;
   ....
   }
}
```

Comment: I am talking about Customizing android keyboard dude.

Comment: Won't you enter this keyboard input to a specific area like a texbox? Where will you enter this specific input? to your own application input areas or anywhere on device?

Comment: I am working on a custom keyboard like SwiftKey Keyboard, Swype Keyboard, etc.