# Multiplying an entered number in android

Tags: android

I am working on an android app and need some help with a calculation code. A user is required to enter a value 1-5000000 into a text field (EditText), a button (calculate) is pressed, when this happens the entered number needs to be multiplied by 10% and the answer displayed on screen in a text field (EditText).
Below is the code i am working on:

```
    public void operation(){
    if(optr.equals("*")){
        amt = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());
        amt = num * 10%;
        num1.setText(Integer.toString(amt));
    }
```

Comment: Describe your problem.

Comment: So what's he problem?

Comment: you do not specify if you expect an integer or floating point result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
int amt = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());
int result = amt/10;
```

Btw, you are trying to multiply your EditText and not its value in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code:

```
public void operation(){
    if(optr.equals("*")){ // what is the optr?
        amt = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());
        amt *= 10%; //You must use the value here, not the EditText
        num1.setText(String.valueOf(amt));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this; % is not a percent operator in programming context.

```
public void operation(){
if(optr.equals("*")){
    amt = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());
    amt = num / 10;
    num1.setText(Integer.toString(amt));
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a text change listener like in the answer here: [android edittext onchange listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134144/android-edittext-onchange-listener)

you can also use RXJava and RXbinding to create an observable that emits the value of the edittext whenever it is changed

EDIT: nevermind didnt notice you were running this from a method

Answer (score 0):

**In Java you can not multiply directly with 10% to get the 10% of any number.**

Changes have been made in your code by commenting your line.
considering float as input.

```
public void operation(){
    if(optr.equals("*")){
        //amt = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());
        // amt = num * 10%;
        amt = Float.parseFloat(num.getText().toString());
        amt = num/10;
        num1.setText(amt+"");

        //num1.setText(Integer.toString(amt));
    }
}
```