# Create a method that runs when editText is changing

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android development and I want to create a method that runs every time my editText is changed.

In **swift** I use this function:

```
func fieldChanged(textfieldChange: UITextField){

}
```

I can't find anywhere a similar function for Java and Android Studio, are there any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android edittext onchange listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134144/android-edittext-onchange-listener)

Comment: Why is javascript as tag? Do you ask for Java/Kotlin or are you using javascript and Ionic, Electron or similar...?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Globally declare a variable

private TextWatcher mTextWatcher;

// Call textChanger() method in onCreate

private void textChanger() {
        mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() == 6 && mEditText.getText().toString().trim().equals("some value to check"))
mEditTextOther.requestFocus();
                else
                    mEditText.setError("enter correct");
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
        };
        mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    });
```

Comment: Where should I add this? I'm new to Android Studio and I'm a little confussed.

Comment: did your nedd for andord or xmarin