# SubString selection in EditText Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there a way to capture text once `#` pressed until spacebar is pressed in `EditText`? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have tried the text watcher interface on editText?https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Do you mean you want to watch for the character '#' and then capture text until the spacebar is pressed? If so, I would recommend reading up on a text change listener (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134144/android-edittext-onchange-listener)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanna ask. Donno why downvoted. The query is simple and straightforward. Will check the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First attach `addTextChangedListener` to your `edittext` and call a method which will match a particular condition like below:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    try {
    String capturedString = getText(s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 
});
```

The above code will try to populate `capturedString` everytime a new character is added to the `edittext` field.

Now write another function `getText()` like below:

```
public String getText(String s) {
    String startChar = "#";
    String endChar   = " ";
    String output = getStringBetweenTwoChars(s, startChar, endChar);
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

This method will match the provided string for `#` and `space`. If found, it will return the captured string if not found, it will throw an error (This error will be captured in `catch` block of the above code)

Now finally, write the below function which will intake a character sequence and two charecters and match the charecter sequence with the provided charecters and return the string between them:

```
public String getStringBetweenTwoChars(String input, String startChar, String endChar) {
try {
    int start = input.indexOf(startChar);
    if (start != -1) {
        int end = input.indexOf(endChar, start + startChar.length());
        if (end != -1) {
            return input.substring(start + startChar.length(), end);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return input;
}
```

Hope this helps :)