# Cannot type in EditText when it's in a custom dialog

Tags: android, frontend

I'm trying to get some numbers as user input from a custom dialog. I used an `edittext` for this purpose. when `edittext` is clicked the soft keyboard pops up normally, but when I'm trying to type numbers it won't show anything in `edittext`. only the decimal point `.` can be typed.

I've also tried this without limiting characters to numbers, and I've got a weird result, in this case, I can type all characters to `edittext`, but `backspace` only works on non-number characters, when I type numbers `backspace` won't remove them. this problem only happens in the dialog and not in `activities` or `fragments`.
what am i doing wrong?

Also i have to mention that I'm using English keyboard.

***custom dialog layout:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_180sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_130sdp"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Trading.main_background"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_15sdp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Trading.main_background">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_up_down"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/gray_1"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_17sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_27sdp"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:background="@drawable/border_spinner"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_55sdp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Spinner
                android:theme="@style/Theme.Trading.main_textview"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_1"
                android:id="@+id/alarm_spinner"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_90sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp" />



        </RelativeLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_money"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/gray_1"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_53sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_25sdp"/>

        <EditText
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_1"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_48sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_55sdp"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_90sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_symbol"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/gray_1"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_89sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_25sdp"/>





    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

***and i show this dialog ti user with code below:***

```
    public void showDialog(){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_add_alarm);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));


        dialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode,
                                 KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning **true** in your dialogue method. That is the cause of your problem.
Use below code.

```
 public void showDialog(){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_add_alarm);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
   

    dialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode,
                             KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            //just replace your return boolean to false. it will work
            return false;
        }
    });

    dialog.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the EditText and handle the onTextChanged event for it.

I am expecting to see something like this

`customDialog_EditText = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogedittext);`

Here is a good example of a custom dialog with a working EditText:
https://www.edumobile.org/android/custom-dialog-with-edittext-in-android-development/

maybe you need a TextWatcher as outlined here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11134227/15119767